# MGF and Correlation

Tags: probability-distributions, correlation, moment-generating-functions, jacobian

Let $X,Y$ be iid RVs with common standard normal density. Let $U=X+Y$ and $V=X^2+Y^2$. Find the MGF of the random variable $(U,V)$. Also, find the correlation coefficient between $U$ and $V$. Are $U$ and $V$ independent?

Based on sums and squares of Normal RVs, I would say that U is N(0,2) and that V is ChiSquare(2). Then the marginal densities are f(u)=$\frac 1{\sqrt {4\pi}}e^{-u^2/4}$ for $-\infty<u<\infty$ and f(v)=$\frac 12e^{-v^2/2}$ for $0<v<\infty$

Then I believe the Jacobian of this transformation is J=$\frac 1{2{\sqrt {2v-u^2}}}$ (not sure on this) which would then make the joint pdf f(u,v)=$\frac 1{\sqrt {4\pi}}e^{-v/2}(2v-u^2)^{-1/2}$

I'm not sure where to go from here or if this is even right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to calculate the joint density, you just need to calculate the moment generating function. Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, the MGF factorizes in the following way:

$$E[e^{t_1U + t_2V}] = E[e^{(t_1 X + t_2 X^2) + (t_1 Y + t_2 Y^2)}] = E[e^{t_1 X + t_2 X^2}] E[e^{t_1 Y + t_2 Y^2}]$$

Now you just need to calculate the integral
$$\begin{align*}
&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int \limits_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(t_1x + t_2x^2 - x^2/2) \, dx \\
={}& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int \limits_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left((t_2 - 1/2)\left(x + \frac{t_1}{2 \sqrt{t_2 - 1/2}}\right)^2 - \frac{t_1^2}{4t_2 - 2} \right) \, dx \\
={}& \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - 2t_2}} \exp\left(\frac{t_1^2}{2 - 4t_2}\right)
\end{align*}$$

(The integral diverges for $t_2 \ge \frac{1}{2}$).

To get the mixed moments of $U$ and $V$, you need to consider the connection between the derivative of the MGF and the mixed moments. As for the independence, you just need to check if the moment generating function factorizes in the way that it does with independent random variables.

Comment: That integral you wrote is the MGF of (U,V)? Then for independence I would first see if the correlation coefficient is nonzero.

Comment: This is not yet the MGF. Try to understand the steps that I have written and where the integrals come from.

Comment: So just to make sure I'm following: you factorized the MGF, then reordered the exponents to group X and Y terms. The integral then would be the first expectation, since that is the e term multiplied by the pdf of a standard normal X, integrated across the real line.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Ok so by doing the same for Y, I get that the joint MGF is $\frac 1{1-2t_2}*e^{({\frac {t_1^2}{1-2t_2}})}$

Comment: Could you confirm this? (Sorry if my MathJax is not so good yet)

Comment: I get the same result

Comment: Perfect. Then I obtained that U and V are uncorrelated but not independent.

Comment: Quick question: how did you get the square root in the integral above?

Comment: That's from the linear substitution.

Comment: In the second integral there, where did the - sign come from between x and the t1 term?

Comment: My bad, that should be a plus. Thanks, I've fixed it now.